# Context related code highlighting with t-vim

Tags: context, highlighting, t-vim

```
Notice that \inlinec{\n} represents only a single character.
An escape sequence like \inlinec{\n} provides
a general and extensible mechanism for representing
hard-to-type or invisible characters.
Among the others that C provides are \inlinec{\t} for tab,
\inlinec{\b} for backspace,
\inlinec{\"} for the double quote,
and \inlinec{\\} for the backslash itself.
There is a complete list in Section 2.3.
```

will produce

[image]

In the example above, highlighting  does not work correctly.
So, we shall provide more information to ConTeXt.

Is it possible to do some thing like `\codecontext{printf("text\inline{\n}");}` to produce the right highlighting for '\n', '\t', '\b', ...?

Comment: @Aditya filter expert

Comment: `\n` is not a valid C syntax! You'll get the right highlighting if you use `\inlinec{"\n"}`, which is valid C code. The highlighting produced by `t-vim` is the same as what you'll see if you type the content of the macro directly in `vim` and the the syntax to C.

Comment: I understand. How ever, if we type `\inlinec{"\n"}`, we get extra double quotations. :D.

Comment: But that is how C syntax highlighting works. \n etc are special only inside a string. The easiest solution will be to write a vim syntax highlighting scheme for your "language" and then use `\definevimtyping[...][syntax=mylangualge]`.  For example, if you set the syntax to `context`, everything starting with abackslash will be highlighted.